# Python limiting character input

Tags: python

I'm trying to only allow the letters a, b or c in an input for a .dat file in a Python program (code below), but I'm having difficulty getting the program to do this correctly.

```
varClass = "class" + input("Which class are you in? [A/B/C]: ").lower() + ".dat"
if not re.match("^[a-c]*$", varClass):
    print("Enter the correct class number")
```

This is what I have already, but it still continues to run even after an incorrect character has been entered.

Comment: `varClass` already contains "c" and "a" because you preppend "class" :X

Answer (score 1):

```
varClass = "class" + input("Which class are you in? [A/B/C]: ").lower() + ".dat"
if not re.match("^class[a-c]\.dat$", varClass):
    print("Enter the correct class number")
```

Your `match` will always return `false` as `match` matches from beginning and you have `class` at the beginning.

Comment: acctually it will always match true due to that "class" begins with c

Comment: @Johan if input is `c` only then it will match.else it will fail

Comment: I'm talking about his code, it will always match true, @vks your code is correct

Answer (score 0):

Take the input first, check it then add `class` and `.dat`, you have already added class and .dat  before you check the input, adding then checking is doing things a bit backwards:

```
allowed = {"a","b","c"}
inp =  input("Which class are you in? [A/B/C]: ").lower()
if not allowed.issuperset(inp):
     print("Enter the correct class number")
else:
     var = "class{}.dat".format(inp)
```

If you have certain specific letter combinations you will have to add those in the set and check:

```
    inp =  input("Which class are you in? [A/B/C]: ").lower()
    if inp.lower() not in {"ab","ac"}:
         print("Enter the correct class number")
    else:
         var = "class{}.dat".format(inp)
```

Comment: While your `not all` logic matches the OPs, I don't think the OPs is actually correct....

Comment: As the input is being written to a .dat file, how can I implement this as well?

Comment: @JordanBolton,  the same way, if you only want abc in the class name then the logic is the same.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham not sure a class of `abababababcababa` should really be valid... - think it should be that it's either A or B or C... one letter, that's it

Comment: @JonClements, True but I have no idea what the class names can be

Comment: @Padraic true, I'm going by the input prompt of the OP's code, and also the fact that there's about 50+ questions I've seen about asking which class someone is in (A/B/C), then taking names - the last three scores, finding the average and sorting them etc... looks like the very start of an assignment :)

Comment: @JonClements. lol I have seen a multitude of scores and averages too over past few weeks, apparently it is some college course, I have not seen one so early in the process though :)